# Insert records to a table with loop from an other table data

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have two tables like this:

**SupplyList** (`IDSupply` is the primary key)

```
IDSupply  PartName  Qty
--------- --------- ----
1         C         10
2         B         4
```

**SupplyIndex** (`IDSupply` and `Index` are the compound primary key)

```
IDSupply  PartName  Index
--------- --------- ------
1           C        2
1           C        3
1           C        7
1           C        9
1           C        10
```

These tables are related to each other with `IDSupply`.

I want to insert missed records to `SupplyIndex` table by a query in SQL. In other words, my expected result is `SupplyIndex` table like below (`Index` must include numbers from 1 to `Qty` from `SupplyList` table)

```
IDSupply  PartName  Index
--------- --------- ------ (result)
1           C        1
1           C        2
1           C        3
1           C        4
1           C        5
1           C        6
1           C        7
1           C        8
1           C        9
1           C        10
2           B        1
2           B        2
2           B        3
2           B        4
```

I did this job in my VB.Net application before and now I want to do it in SQL Server directly.

Would you please help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Test Data:**

```
create table #supplylist
(
idsupply int,
partname char(20),
qty int
)

insert into #supplylist
select 1,'a',10
union all 
select 2,'c',4

create table #idsupply
(
 idsupply int,
 partname  char(20),
 indexx int
 )

 insert into #idsupply
 select 1,'a',10
 union all
 select 2,'c',3
```

I used Numbers table to accomplish this

```
with cte
as
(
select 
idsupply,
partname,n
from 
#supplylist t
cross apply
(
select n from numbers where n <=qty
)b
```

--final part to check and isnert in other table..same query as above with insert and exists

```
with cte
as
(
select 
idsupply,
partname,n
from 
#supplylist t
cross apply
(
select n from numbers where n <=qty
)b
)
insert into #idsupply
select * from cte  t1 where not exists (select 1 from #idsupply t2 where t2.indexx=t1.n)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. it doesn't work for me. please check my edit in SupplyIndex Table too. I need moor help. Thanks

Comment: Can you provide more info.You need to replace your table names and install numbers table

Answer (score 0):

```
Create Table #SupplyList(IDSupply int Primary Key,  PartName char(10),Qty int);
Insert #SupplyList(IDSupply, PartName, Qty) Values
(1,         'C',         10),
(2,         'B',         4);
Create Table #SupplyIndex(IDSupply int,  PartName char(10), [Index] int Primary Key (IdSupply, [Index]));
Insert #SupplyIndex(IDSupply, PartName, [Index]) Values
(1,           'C',        2),
(1,           'C',        3),
(1,           'C',        7),
(1,           'C',        9),
(1,           'C',        10);
;With cteMax As
(Select Max([Index]) As MaxIndex From #SupplyIndex),
cteNumbers As
(Select 1 As Number
Union All
Select Number + 1
From cteNumbers n
Cross Join cteMax m
Where n.Number < m.MaxIndex)
Merge #SupplyIndex t
Using (Select sl.IDSupply, sl.PartName, n.Number As Qty From #SupplyList sl Inner Join cteNumbers n On n.Number <= sl.Qty) s
On s.IDSupply = t.IDSupply And s.PartName = t.PartName And s.Qty = t.[Index]
When Not Matched Then Insert(IDSupply, PartName, [Index])  Values(s.IDSupply, s.PartName, s.Qty);

Select * From #SupplyIndex;


go
Drop Table #SupplyList;
go
Drop Table #SupplyIndex
```